# Can the Israeli prime minister sign diplomatic deals in the interim period before a new government, after the Knesset dissolves?

Tags: israel, international-relations

Anyone who's been keeping up with global diplomatic-strategic news should know about the historic normalization deal between Israel and the United Arab Emirates (UAE).

The final signing of the deal is tentatively scheduled about 3 weeks from the first announcement (source: https://www.timesofisrael.com/trump-annexation-off-the-table-at-least-now-israel-suspending-settlements/). This would place it in early September.

A more recent article indicated that Israel's unity coalition government is badly dysfunctional and will probably dissolve soon for failing to approve a budget in time (source: https://www.timesofisrael.com/senior-likud-official-says-coalition-not-functioning-new-elections-likely/). More specifically, the Knesset must either approve a budget or a bill delaying the requirement by August 25. If that fails, new elections are automatically called and the current prime minister - Benjamin Netanyahu - becomes *interim* prime minister until a new government is formed.

The question: If the governing coalition collapses due to failing the budget deadline BEFORE the UAE normalization deal can be finalized, can Netanyahu sign the normalization as interim prime minister? Or will Israel have to wait for a new governing coalition before signing the deal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between regular and interim as far as signing docs is concerned. A PM can sign whether he/she is regular or interim.

Comment: While this is true, the supreme court has ruled in the past that an interim government shouldn't make significant policy changes, and mostly maintain status until a new government is appointed. So had we been in an interim government now, someone could appeal the supreme court asking for a delay.